# How do we enable antialiasing on XNA-Silverlight hybrid projects?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, antialiasing

In XNA we just need to do this: GraphicsDevice.PreferMultisampling = true, but there is not such property in XNA-Silverlight hybrid projects.

How do we enable antialiasing in 3D games based on XNA-Silverlight hybrid project template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/103106/612093.aspx), maybe that's what you're looking for.